# Trick/Workaround for cross reference between files without xr

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, labels, xr

I have a main manuscript and a supplementary materials tex files.
These are based on templates by the AGU journals, therefore it is not recommended to add any other packages, than those provided.
I need to cross reference the figure in the supplementaries in the main file.
I know a solution can be the xr package, but as said I cannot use it.

Is there a workaround to e.g. list all SI figures and their lables in the MAIN, but without displaying them?

```
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2018}
\begin{document}
I would like to cite \ref{fig:si01}, which is displayed in SI.
....
therefore I would like to include here below a list of figures without displaying them.
In addition they should be renamed 

% first rename figures adding S, and then reset figure counter to zero
\def\appendixID{{S}} % add S to numbering
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\appendixID\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

% second, make a list of not-shown figures
% this does the job but is note resetting the counter:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\label{fig:si01}
\end{figure}

% this reset the counter and add the "S" but it's showing the figure caption, while I want nothing to be displayed:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{}\label{fig:si01}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!